# Открепление внутреннего фрагмента перед откреплением родительского

Tags: android, android-fragment

Наблюдаю странное поведение фрагментов.
Есть три фрагмента: А, В и С. Добавляем А на активити. Внутри А создаем В и добавляем на А через childFragmentManager в А.onViewCreated. Затем по действию пользователя запускаем анимацию, которая заменяет фрагмент А на активити на фрагмент С. При запуске этой транзацкии сначала из а мгновенно пропадает В, и только потом запускается анимация с тем что осталось в А.

Выглядит будто при попытке открепить А сначала открепляются все дочерние фрагменты, и только потом запускается транзакция. Но! Если В был создан не программно, а описан в лайоуте А, то этой проблемы нет. А исчезает вместе с В, как и должно бы быть

Пример проблемы на гитлаб:
https://gitlab.com/restangel1993/fragmentinfragment

add или replace в транзакции - не имеет значения, проблема остается. Как и анимация - пробовал кастомные анимации давать, использовать FramentTransition

Возникает вопрос: а чем отличается фрагмент, созданный программно и добавленный через транзакцию, от фрагмента, созданного при при инфлайте xml? Как не дать В отцепиться от А раньше времени и запороть анимацию?

Comment: Сам не сталкивался, но похоже проблема старая и в основном использовались всякие хаки типа скриншотов фрагмента и т.п. Но вот тут предлагают что-то дельное: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859132/nested-fragments-transitioning-incorrectly

Comment: Вариант со скрином тоже обдумывал, но это как-то совсем не камильфо... Плюс главный вопрос все таки в причине разницы в поведении. Прописанный в xml фрагмент не требует никаких костылей, в чем же разница? Попытался понять смысл происходящего по вашей ссылке... нем смог)) Может еще вернусь и со свежей головой пойму что там происходит

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы решил таки вопрос. Внезапно помог следующий подход:

1. В родительском фрагменте создаем экземпляр дочернего в init блоке
   или в onCreate.
2. в onViewCreated прикрепляем дочерний фрагмент с
   помощью childFragmentManager
3. в onDestroyView открепляем дочерний
       фрагмент

Как ни странно, при последующей анимации родительского фрагмента дочерний остается на месте, видимо открепление в onDestroyView не вызывает перерисовку